# stack replaces all the entries in it with the last pushed element

Tags: java, eclipse

I need some help on this one as I couldnt find a logical explanation for this anywhere. Maybe it is just a small mistake but I have been at the code for such a long time that I just cant see it. I have added comments where I am trying to push elements in my stack. I have two stacks one for all the operators and one for operands. The operator stack works fine but the operand stack is behaving weird. When I am trying to push elements it somehow replaces the stack elements with the latest element that I push. Whn I pop it returns the last element at all times.  I have two different classes as operators and operands. Please let me know if you need the code for it. EDIT: The other classes dont do anything much though just a couple of getters, setters and checking for validity of tokens. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
   import java.util.*;
   public class Evaluator {
private Stack<Operand> opdStack;
private Stack<Operator> oprStack;
public Evaluator() {
    opdStack = new Stack<Operand>();
    oprStack = new Stack<Operator>();
// HashMap<String, Operator> operators = new HashMap<String, Operator>();

        Operator.operators.put("+",new AdditionOperator());
        Operator.operators.put("-", new SubtractionOperator());
        Operator.operators.put("*",new MultiplyOperator());
        Operator.operators.put("/",new DivisionOperator());
        Operator.operators.put("#",new BogusHash());

}

public int eval(String expr) {
    String tok = "";
    // init stack - necessary with operator priority schema;
    // the priority of any operator in the operator stack other then
    // the usual operators - "+-*/" - should be less than the priority
    // of the usual operators 

    Operator newOpr = Operator.operators.get("#");

    oprStack.push(newOpr); 

    String delimiters = "+-*/#! ";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expr,delimiters,true);
    // the 3rd arg is true to indicate to use the delimiters as tokens, too
    // but we'll filter out spaces
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if ( !(tok = st.nextToken()).equals(" ")) { // filter out spaces
            //System.out.println("equals");
            if (Operand.check(tok)) { // check if tok is an operand
                //System.out.println("tokens = "+tok);
                //opdStack.push(new Operand ("0"));

                opdStack.push(new Operand(tok));
                System.out.println("stack peek "+ opdStack.peek().getValue());

                //System.out.println(opdStack);
                //System.out.println(oprStack);

            } else {
                //System.out.println("tokens = "+tok);
                //System.out.println(newOpr);

                if (!Operator.operators.containsKey(tok)) {
                    //System.out.println("tokens = "+tok);
                    //System.out.println(newOpr);
                    System.out.println("*****invalid token******"); System.exit(1);
                }
                Operator newOpr2 = Operator.operators.get(tok); // POINT 1
                //System.out.println("Operator = "+oprStack.peek().priority());
                while ( (oprStack.peek()).priority() >= newOpr2.priority()) {
                    //System.out.println("tokens while = "+tok);

                    System.out.println("tokens = "+tok);
                    Operator oldOpr = ((Operator)oprStack.pop());
                    //System.out.println("Opr"+oldOpr.priority());
                    Operand op2 = (Operand)opdStack.pop();

                    Operand op1 = (Operand)opdStack.pop();
                    System.out.println("run till here");
                    opdStack.push(oldOpr.execute(op1,op2));


                    System.out.println("Final res pushed opd= " + opdStack.peek().getValue());
                }
                oprStack.push(newOpr2);
                //System.out.println("operand "+opdStack.toString());

            }

        }




    }

    //System.out.println("pop op2 = "+opdStack.pop().getValue()+" and pop op1 = "+opdStack.pop().getValue());
    Operator newOp2 = ((Operator)oprStack.pop());
    Operand op2 = (Operand)opdStack.get(0);
    Operand op1 = (Operand)opdStack.get(1);
    System.out.println("opd = "+ op1.getValue() + op2.getValue());
    opdStack.push(newOp2.execute(op2, op1));

    System.out.println("Full Stack opd size= "+ opdStack.size());

    //System.out.println("Full Stack opd= "+ opdStack.toString());

    Operand res = (Operand) opdStack.pop();



    return res.getValue();

   }
  }
```

My Operand.java class

```
 public class Operand {

 static int val=0;
private static String strval="";
public Operand(String tok) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     strval = tok;
     val = Integer.parseInt(strval);
    // System.out.println("value = "+val);
}

public Operand(int value){
    val = value;
    //System.out.println("value = "+val);
}

public static boolean check(String tok) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean bool;
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(tok);
        bool = true;
    } catch (Exception e){
        //System.out.println("Type conversion "+e);
        bool = false;
    }
    return bool;
}

public int getValue(){
    //int re = Integer.parseInt(this.toString());
    System.out.println("return value = " + val);
    return val;

}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working instead of just saying it's behaving weird, please ?

Comment: what its doing is that when I try to pop the elements of the stack it returns the last element pushed all the time. EDIT: so when i try to execute it uses the last popped element twice and gives me the result.

Comment: Yes, because it is a stack. Stack are LIFO (last in first out) meaning that it put object on the top, and take from the top too. Like a stack of plates for example. The last plate pushed on the stack is the first one you will take.

Comment: try debugging through your while loop. it seems that's where the stack removal occurs

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard yes but after it has removed it should remove the next element. My stack retrieves the same element multiple times. Even after popping once it has the same element below it.

Comment: @coffeeaddict I did try.. The values are coming as the same there as well. and I am not popping anythng before that.!

Comment: what do you mean by 'values are coming as the same there as well?' have you tried to see what your stack looks like in every iteration of your nested loop? your inner while look pops twice but pushes once, so it tells me that, at least your stack will get smaller for each iteration. furthermore, if this inner loop keeps running, each iteration will shrink your stack by 1. if you are seeing this behavior while debugging, you should see if this is behaving the way you want it to

Comment: @coffeeaddict I just figured out the mistake.! in my operand class I have a method getValue() which returns the value of the operand. But it is set to the last element that I push. I have kept the variable static that is why it was giving me that error. Thank you!